# How to pass String variable (s_code) to Jsoup pseudo selector " :containsOwn(text) " instead of String value at text

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get parent row of a column whose value matches the string i stored in variable `s_code`, from a table in a HTML page

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .data("selZone", z_code)
            .data("selDivision", d_code)
            .data("divisionWise", "DivisionWise")
            .post();
Element column=doc.selectFirst("td:containsOwn(s_code)"); 
                                              //s_code is a String variable
Element parentRow=column.parent();
Elements columns=parentRow.select("td");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value of the variable `s_code` replace "s_code" in `Element column=doc.selectFirst("td:containsOwn(s_code)");` You can use `String.format` as below.

```java
Element column=doc.selectFirst(String.format("td:containsOwn(%s)",s_code));
```

This will replace `%s` with the value of `s_code`